# prove a contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis

In the metric space $c[0,1]$ (the sup metric) . Suppose that $c \in (0,1)$, the function $f:C[0,1] \rightarrow R $ is $f(x) = 1-cf(1-x)$. why constant function is the only function $f$ for which the above relationship holds?

I have no idea how to start this proof.

Comment: Is there an overlapping notation? Which is the difference between $c[0,1]$ and $c \in (0,1)$???

Comment: @the_candyman sry for any confusion. the $C[0,1]$ is a sup metric space and $c \in (0,1)$ are some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = 1-cf(1-x)\implies f(1-x)=1-cf(1-(1-x))=1-cf(x).$$ Thus

$$f(x) = 1-cf(1-x)=1-c(1-cf(x))=1-c+c^2f(x)\implies (1-c^2)f(x)=1-c.$$ Since $c\in (0,1)$ we have $$(1+c)f(x)=1$$ or, equivalently, $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+c}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) +c f(1-x) =1$$
$$f(1-x) +c f(x) =1$$
hence

$$(1-c) f(x) - (1-c) f(1-x) =0$$
$$f(x) =f(1-x) $$
and 
$$f(x) =\frac{1}{1+c}$$

Comment: Sure. I've just edited